# Pod installation failed ? No module found

Tags: json, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm running into problems with the installation of Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. I follwed the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rqr3w8scm2E and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Brei27hdnF8&feature=iv&src_vid=Rqr3w8scm2E&annotation_id=annotation_700071403 which includes a description of the installation process.

I created the Pod file [image]

and my pod install seemed to work as well [image]

Now I'm not quite sure if I missed something. I thought maybe the two tests in the in the pod file need the two pods as well, but even after i tried that it still didn't work.

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to open the `<your project name>.xcworkspace` file with Xcode in your project root folder instead of the regular `<your project name>.xcodeproj`?

CocoaPods creates `<your project name>.xcodeproj` for you once you install the pods and requires you to use it from that moment on. You can type in the terminal `open <your project name>.xcodeproj` and Xcode will open it for you.

Comment: Do you mean that the pod file needs to be in the xcodeproj file itself, rather than in the general folder? 

Because when I open XCode I open both .xcodeproj and xcworkspace. 
If I open one of them with the terminal command I'm not able to do anythign

Comment: The Podfile must be in the same folder where your `<your project name>.xcodeproj` file is, and once you run `pod install` this will create a `<your project name>.xcworkspace`, which you need to open with Xcode and you will have your dependencies available there.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know I had to open it that way, thanks a lot :D I just used the  normal method, where i open the whole file from xCode. Seems to work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The code itself doesn't seem to be having erros, but i'm not sure if the pods are recognised correctly because i'm now getting this error :

ld: framework not found Pods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Try closing your Xcode (Cmd+q) and from the terminal run `open <your project name>.xcworkspace`

Comment: Can you see the Pods project at the bottom of the Navigator (Cmd+1)?

Comment: Yes, in Frameworks/IOS the Foundation.framework is red and in  Products all 3 frameworks (Alamofire.framework, Pods_SwiftyJSON1_0.Framework and SwiftyJSON.Framework ) are red